# Step reference IntelliJ idea 14.1.4 not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I want to add step reference to a new project. Everything is fine. I create a new project, create new feature file, I copy/paste the code in it. It highlights is - no drama. BUT when I copy/paste the settings that I need in the POM file and I enable the Auto-Import. If I create a new feature file afterwards -> no highlighting, no step references available.

Is there a way to import those POM options and keep the highlighting(step references) ?

Comment: Sounds like a question to ask on an IntelliJ support forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your step files in a directory 'step_definitions' under your features directory.

Using cucumber with protractor and was having the same issue.